# Creating dictionary using two columns and extract value based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel-2010

I was trying to built a dictionary as shown below and extract data based on cell value and display it. Using the below code. How ever im not getting the expected result.

[image]

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Keys() As Variant: Keys = Range("A1:B1").Value2
    Dim Values() As Variant: Values = Range("A2:B7").Value2
    RangeToDict Keys, Values
End Sub
Function RangeToDict(Keys() As Variant, Values() As Variant) As Dictionary
    Set RangeToDict = New Dictionary
    For i = 1 To UBound(Keys)
        RangeToDict.Add Keys(i, 1), Values(i, 1)
        Debug.Print Keys(i, 1) & ", " & Values(i, 1)
    Next
End Function
```

I want to create a dictionary as shown the image and if i search for **AA value** in the dictionary i need to get the **1, 2, 3 values in available columns**.

***Note: I have nearly 70k data for this dictionary hope this would be the fastest way***

COIVD 19 impacted my job now i got one and trying on my feet. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Keys have to be unique! So, `{1, 2, 3, 6, 7}` can be used as keys, and `{'AA', 'BB'}` can be used as values.

Comment: @MaciejLos Thank you! now im working on extracting the data..

Comment: @MaciejLos just one doubt can extract keys using values in dictionary? If yes please guide me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't actually know why do you have 2 arrays (1 with headers, 1 with data) but this code would store all your Index from column A with all their values (comma separated) from column B:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    Dim Keys As Variant: Keys = Range("A2:B7").Value
    Dim MyKeys As Dictionary: Set MyKeys = New Dictionary
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To UBound(Keys)
        With MyKeys
            If .Exists(Keys(i, 1)) Then
                MyKeys(Keys(i, 1)) = MyKeys(Keys(i, 1)) & "," & Keys(i, 2)
            Else
                .Add Keys(i, 1), Keys(i, 2)
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Damian for the code. I'm getting type mismatch error in line For i = 1 To UBound(Keys)

Comment: Sorry @Linga, forgot to declare the `i` try with the edited code.

Comment: No worries @Damian i tried the same but still getting the same error...  lets see if anything to be fixed.

Comment: @Linga it works for me... `For i = 1 To Ubound(Keys)` only goes from 1 To 7 in your case, unless `Keys` is empty...

Comment: Please see the image https://pasteboard.co/Jr9QgTXu.png

Comment: @Linga that means you only have 1 string in your `Keys` variable, that's why you can't loop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221494/discussion-between-linga-and-damian).

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue and, IMHO, is a key failing of VBA in that it does not allow COllection or Scripting.DIctionary Objects to be populated using arrays.  I created my own dictionary object (Kvp) which does allow the dictionary object to be populated using arrays.  You can download the Kvp object from [here](https://github.com/SteveLaycock/Kvp) if you wish to try it out.

Using a Kvp dictionary object your code above would become

```
Dim myKvp as Kvp
Set myKvp=new Kvp
myKvp.AddByKeyFromArrays  Range("A1:B1").Value2, Range("A2:B7").Value2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the next approach, please. Using a `Function`, you firstly need to receive the returned dictionary from the function and do something with it. Then, no need of two arrays. If you insist, the result can be a dictionary of dictionaries, one of them containing only the columns headers...

The dictionary keys are the unique values of column A:A and the items ar arrays, too:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Keys() As Variant: Keys = Range("A1:B1").Value2
    Dim Values() As Variant: Values = Range("A2:B7").Value2
    Dim Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, El As Variant
    Set Dict = RangeToDict(Keys, Values)
    
    For Each El In Dict.Keys
       Debug.Print El, Join(Dict(El), ", ")
    Next
End Sub

Function RangeToDict(Keys() As Variant, Values() As Variant) As Dictionary
    Dim Dict As New Scripting.Dictionary, i As Long. Keys() array not needed...
        For i = 1 To UBound(Values)
            If Not Dict.Exists(Values(i, 1)) Then
                Dict.Add Values(i, 1), Array(Values(i, 2))
            Else
                Dict(Values(i, 1)) = Split(Join(Dict(Values(i, 1)), ",") & "," & Values(i, 2), ",")
            End If
        Next i
    Set RangeToDict = Dict
End Function
```